# Xcode linker error and pod install indicates only 3 dependencies out of 4

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

In Xcode 10.1, I'm getting a linker error surrounding SwiftCharts. This is after I began running 10.2, and needed to revert to 10.1, because of an Xcode bug. I shut down Xcode and cleaned the pods with the following:

```
  rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
  rm -rf Pods
  rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
  pod deintegrate
  pod setup
  pod install
```

which resulted in no DerivedData. The output of the install was the following:

```
pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Realm (3.14.1)
Installing RealmSwift (3.14.1)
Installing SwiftCharts (0.6.5)
Installing SwiftGraph (2.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.
```

At this point, there is no data in DerivedData.

When I startup Xcode, I get a linker error:

```
: Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Project-gwajzqdypdbykjhkkbcpqgffxwio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm'
: Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Project-gwajzqdypdbykjhkkbcpqgffxwio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift'
: Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Project-gwajzqdypdbykjhkkbcpqgffxwio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftCharts'
: Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Project-gwajzqdypdbykjhkkbcpqgffxwio/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftGraph'
: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In the editor:

```
ld: framework not found SwiftCharts
```

Underneath DerivedData, in the folder Debug-iphonesimulator, I'm not seeing any frameworks that the warnings are indicating should be there. **Why are the framework directories missing, and why is SwiftCharts installing but not available to the linker?**

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

target 'ProjectCoreData' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SwiftCharts', '~> 0.6.3'
  pod 'SwiftGraph'
  pod 'OverlayContainer'
  pod 'RealmSwift'

  # Pods for ProjectCoreData

  target 'ProjectCoreDataTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'ProjectCoreDataUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

"Podfile" 24L, 549C
```

Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - OverlayContainer (2.0.0)
  - Realm (3.14.1):
    - Realm/Headers (= 3.14.1)
  - Realm/Headers (3.14.1)
  - RealmSwift (3.14.1):
    - Realm (= 3.14.1)
  - SwiftCharts (0.6.5)
  - SwiftGraph (3.0.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - OverlayContainer
  - RealmSwift
  - SwiftCharts (~> 0.6.3)
  - SwiftGraph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `SwiftCharts (0.6.5)` is built for swift 5.0 with Xcode 10.2, so it's not compatible with Xcode 10.1, just use older version of `SwiftCharts` (0.6.3 or older).

Comment: Hm. Looks like I have 0.6.3 specified in the Podfile, but 0.6.5 keeps getting chosen.

Comment: @Joe Could you update you question with the content of your Podfile?

Comment: `~> 0.6.3` means not lower than `0.6.3`, and because you have installed `0.6.5` before, cocoapods would uses higher version instead, so just use `0.6.3` without `~>`.

Comment: Got farther - getting segmentation faults. It's definitely a different problem, I'll mark this as the answer, thanks.